# How to get the values of the same attribute of 3 nodes with the same name using XPath in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following nodes of a XML file:

```
<definitions 
  xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
  xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" 
  xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
  xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  id="Definition" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MinimalExample" 
  typeLanguage="http://www.java.com/javaTypes" 
  expressionLanguage="http://www.mvel.org/2.0" 
  xs:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd"
>
  <process processType="Private" isExecutable="true" id="com.sample.HelloWorld" name="Hello World">
    <!-- nodes -->
    <startEvent id="_1" name="StartProcess" />
    <scriptTask id="_2" name="Hello">
      <script>System.out.println("Hello World");</script>
    </scriptTask>
    <endEvent id="_3" name="EndProcess">
      <terminateEventDefinition />
    </endEvent>
    <!-- connections -->
    <sequenceFlow id="_1-_2" sourceRef="_1" targetRef="_2" />
    <sequenceFlow id="_2-_3" sourceRef="_2" targetRef="_3" />
  </process>
</definitions>
```

I want to get all the values of the sourceRef attribute of each sequenceFlow node using XPath.

I built a for loop:

```
if (n.getNodeName().equals("sequenceFlow")) {
    countsequenceFlows ++;

    for (int i=0; i<=countsequenceFlows;i++) {
        sourceRef = xml.getParameterString("(//sequenceFlow/@sourceRef)[i]");
        System.out.println(sourceRef);
    }
}
```

But I don't get anything in the output. I think I've made an error in my XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the `sourceRef` attribute of the `i`-th `sequenceFlow` node. Use this:

```
sourceRef = xml.getParameterString("//sequenceFlow[" + i + "]/@sourceRef");
```

Comment: You need to populate `i` into the query string. Have updated my answer. Wich programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using JAVA, and I get the same blank line even after the modification

Comment: Does the `xml` uses namespaces?

Comment: I've added my xml file

Comment: You need to register the namespaces and then access elements using the namespace. What type has `xml`?

Comment: Is it really neccessary? 
I've never done this before, and I have to change all my code

Comment: What type has `xml` ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question